# Why does God hate sexual immorality?

Tags: sexuality, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, arayot

After failing to curse the Jewish people, Bilaam advised Balak to lure the Jews into sexual immorality "for their God hates zimah" (Sanhedrin 106a). We also find that many cases of forbidden relations incur capital punishment (Lev.20). And before the Flood in Noah's time: "the earth was corrupt before God.. for all flesh corrupted their way" (Gen. 6:17), Rabbi Yishmael says - this refers to sexual immorality (Sanhedrin 57a).

Why is this so hateful in God's eyes? Is it due to the consequences of the breakdown of family or some other reason?

Comment: G-d makes the rules and put nature in place with its laws and wants us to maintain them. Whilst the animal kingdom procreate with whomever they see fit, we are "above" the animals and have to control our instincts.

Comment: I think this question could use some more explicating. If I'm understanding you correctly, you're asking why specifically is Bilaam suggesting to tempt them into sexual immorality as opposed to other sins? Because "why does God hate zimah" is simple - he said it's assur, so why WOULDN'T Hashem hate someone transgressing his command?

Comment: See: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38228/8775

Comment: Because it is a disfigurement of love, which, according to [the great Hillel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_the_Elder), represents the bulk of the entire Torah. So if your psyche is viciously assaulted by hatred or malice, you escape the attack of evil by running towards goodness and loving-kindness for safety; but if even love itself has been corrupted, then there is no hope of escape anymore, since even the good, which is supposed to come to one's aid and rescue, has become tainted, and cannot henceforth provide any help.

Answer (score 6):

Rabbi [Mayer Twersky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer_Twersky) writes:

Rashi, commenting on the verse "you shall be holy" (Vayikra 19:2) states:

> "abstain from sexual immorality ... because wherever you find
>   abstention from sexual immorality you find holiness"... Seforno
>   establishes an equation between holiness and eternity. Thus, to be
>   holy means to be forever preoccupied with that which is true and
>   enduring, and to resist the allure of that which is illusory and
>   ephemeral, thereby becoming worthy of eternal life. Hence, the
>   phenomenology of holiness described by Rashi and Ramban. Involvement
>   with sexual immorality and even the indulgence of lust signify the
>   ultimate preoccupation with that which is transient and ephemeral, the
>   very antithesis of holiness.

source: http://www.torahweb.org/torah/2002/parsha/rtwe_kedoshim.html

Comment: I don't see why *"sexual immorality and even the indulgence of lust signify the ultimate preoccupation with that which is transient and ephemeral"*. Maybe a one night stand, but marrying a sister might be a long-term commitment.

Answer (score 4):

This question is interesting because the Gemara begins with this issue "אלהיהם של אלו שונא זימה הוא". But if we read each word of the text we find that the main issue is Idolatry. I will quote a Rashi:

> Gemara (Sanhedrin 106a) quote a verse in Hosea (9, 10):
>   הֵמָּה בָּאוּ בַעַל-פְּעוֹר, וַיִּנָּזְרוּ לַבֹּשֶׁת, וַיִּהְיוּ שִׁקּוּצִים, כְּאָהֳבָם.‏
>   but so soon as they came to Baal-peor, they separated themselves unto the shameful thing, and became detestable like that which they loved. 
>   {Be careful to the words, "love" is the word}
>   *Rashi in Gemara*:
>   
>   כאהבם. מתוך תאות אהבתם לזנות היו משוקצים שכופרין בהקב''ה:‏
>   This was in consequence of their love of "love", they are becoming disgusting because they disavowed G_d.

So, the power of love is the cause of the hate of sexual immorality. Because love knows no laws, it is very harmful. Truth does not go hand in hand with an uncontrollable behavior.

#### Here is a Quotation of the Gemara cited in the OP. Sanhedrin 106a from Talmud Bavli

> But he should have said, What thy people shall do to this people - R`Abba B`Kahana said: It is as one who, cursing himself, refers his malediction to others. 
>
> He [Balaam] said thus to him [Balak].'
>
> **The God of these hates lewdness**, and they are very partial to linen {allusion to beautiful clothes, link between coquetry and arayot}. 
>
> Come, and I will advise thee.
>
> Erect for them tents enclosed by hangings, in which place harlots, old women without, young women within, to sell them linen garments.'
>
> So he erected curtained tents from the snowy mountain [Hermon] as far as Beth ha-Yeshimoth [i.e., right from north to south], and placed harlots in them - old women without, young women within.
>
> And when an Israelite ate, drank, and was merry, and issued forth for a stroll in the market place, the old woman would say to him, 'Dost thou not desire linen garments? ' The old woman offered it at its current value, but the young one for less.
>
> This happened two or three times.
>
> After that she would say to him, 'Thou art now **like one of the family** {friendship, proximity, familiarity}; sit down and choose for thyself.'
>
> Gourds of Ammonite wine lay near her, and at that time Ammonite and heathen wine had not yet been forbidden.
>
> Said she to him, 'Wouldst thou like to drink a glass of wine? ' Having drunk, [his passion] was inflamed, and he exclaimed to her, 'Yield to me!' Thereupon she brought forth an idol from her bosom and said to him, 'Worship this'! 'But I am a Jew', he protested.'
>
> What does that concern thee? ' she rejoined, 'nothing is required but that thou should uncover thyself' - whilst he did not know that such was its worship.'
>
> Nay', [said she,] 'I will not leave thee ere thou hast denied the Torah of Moses thy teacher,' as it is written, They went into Baal-peor, and separated themselves unto that shame, and their abominations were according as **they loved**.

The general prohibition to be in relation with non-Jewish women is linked on verses with Avoda Zara, the problem is the last consequence. See Rambam in [Isure Bia](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&rtype=%u05D8%u05E2%u05E7%u05E1%u05D8%20-%20%u05E4%u05E8%u05D9%u05D9%u05D3%u05D1%u05E8%u05D2&hilchos=27&perek=12). You can see also that the problem with non-Jewish women Min hatora are linked to marriage, not to sexual relations.

#### G_d hate sexual immorality (*of the kind of this mentioned in OP*) because it leads to Idolatry

Comment: Can you include a citation of the Gemara (i.e. Bavli/Yerushalmi, Masekhet, Daf, 'Amud)? Thanks!

Comment: We do find the opposite by the eigel. They only worshipped A.Z. in order to allow themselves forbidden relations.

Comment: @user6591 Very beautiful. At the fundamentals  it is very understandible. Tora and law represent reality and truth (physic and conceptual reallity) AZ and Arayot represent wishes (phantasmal inner world)

Comment: @user6591 note that in Egel an other kind of Arayot, not with non-Jewish was the issue. Here the point is the marrital issue. A very important chiluk

Comment: just idolatry or all other bad stuff such as hedonism, atheism, etc.?

Comment: @ray I think that when we say Idolatry, this is "container-word" which indicate lake of link to G_d. Some chachomim see in Baal Peor, the Idolatry cited in our Gemara  a kind of atheism (see Sichot Musar of Rav Chayim Shmulevits), despite that it is not "mistaber", the idea is that idolatry contain theories as atheism etc.

Answer (score 4):

Ramban (Vayikra 18:6) comments that while the Rambam and Ibn Ezra tried to give a reason that in order to minimize sexual promiscuity the Torah forbade sexual relationships with those women one is regularly with (sibling, parent, child), he himself does not accept that reason. He suggests there may be "secret" reasons, though he doesn't have any tradition for one, and suggests that all the relationships which were forbidden are either of the type that can't produce children or won't establish successful marriages. But he concludes that it is a Decree of the King which we don't really know the reason for.

Comment: does he hold that all mitzvot are but decrees?

Comment: @ray I don't think so. It's a Chok.

Comment: so why does He hate it so much if there is no real reason? arent the mitzvot for us not Him?

Comment: @ray I'm just reporting what the Ramban says in his famous commentary on Chumash.

Comment: ok thanks but the question was why does He hate it so much not what is the reason for the punishments. (according to bilaam)

Comment: @ray Apparently the simple reason is because he said so.

Comment: not very satisfying to say the least. but thanks

Comment: I think it's only the recent Christian-right "homosexuality is immoral" trend in popular culture that is skewing your view. Homosexuality, like other Arayot, is a Chok. There's no moral reason to care where a man ejaculates more than where he defecates. This isn't surprising if you think about it logically a priori.

Comment: so why does the torah refer it as "corruption of the flesh" in parsha noach?

Comment: @ray That isn't a quote from the Torah...

Comment: "And the earth was corrupt before God.. for all flesh corrupted their way" (Gen. 6:17), Rabbi Yishmael says - this refers to sexual immorality (Sanhedrin 57a)

Comment: @ray We already knew God doesn't want us to do it.  So, according to RY, one of the categories of sins of the generation preceding the deluge was sexual sins. What are you getting at?

Comment: just pointing out it is considered "corruption". seems to imply it has a reason. namely it corrupts a person. makes him into an animal. somewhat along @kouty 's answer

Comment: @ray You sure are reading a lot into a translation of a word in Tanakh. Do you have any evidence the verb השחית has the connotations you are assigning to it? You are just making things up. It's your made up Drashas on an English translation vs the Ramban.

Comment: "if you think about it logically" - morality and logic are two different types of glasses. honestly, i am a bit surprised at your choice of words. a talmid chacham should be careful in these things

Comment: @ray Different, I agree. But you are asking for logical reasons for things. You may not be satisfied, but if the Ramban felt this was the best we can do on the simple level, that is certainly noteworthy. btw what words do you find surprising?

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/1063244/rabbi-jonathan-ziring/are-the-arayot-chukim-or-mishpatim/

Answer (score 3):

The reason that God hates immorality is because it deliquesces the human personality. I.e. after a person becomes involved in immorality their personality begins to unravel and become formless.

This contradicts the God ideal of creating free thinking human beings whose conciousness is able to creatively expand and develop harmonious worlds of meaningfulness.

At a fundamental level, someone who engages in immorality has no moral compass, however much they may try to convince themselves otherwise.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: Note the question was about sexual immorality, not immorality in general. You don't seem to address that.

Answer (score 2):

1. THe intimate relations are the most sacred relations in Judaism, as the Shir Hashirim suggests and signifies the closest relations between two entities.
2. A misconduct in those relations (*as prescribed by G-d in the Torah, with or without our understanding*) is automatically the most hateful transgression.

---

In my personal understanding, similarly to Gezel that messes with the pieces of the human souls, sexual transgressions also mess with human souls and require G-d to constantly correct the misdeeds etc.